# Performance of SQL Server in RDS is 5 times slower than MySQL in RDS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, rds

We have a MySQL database with 300 column wide and 100,000 rows stored in the Amazon RDS GovCloud. We migrated the data to MS SQL Server in the same Amazon RDS GovCloud. Each server is identically sized.

The performance of the databases are markedly different. Each database has the same table structure with same indexes, yet a delete of a single record by a 6 column unique key is <100 ms in MySql and >500ms in MSSQL.  Inserts are <300ms in MySQL and >1s in MSSQL Server.

All the indexes are used. Query plans look correct. We just don't see a reason why one can be that different than the other.

Any ideas as to where to look?

Comment: Are there any applications or middleware involved or are you issuing commands via consoles?

Comment: "We migrated the data to MS SQL Server"  Problem found.  lol

Comment: @Ross Bush There was an application, but when we found the problem, we recreated it in the consoles to make sure it wasn't a technology issue. We are comparing speeds from MySQL Workbench (and another I can't think of off the top of my head) and SSMS.

Comment: If you have ruled out network and or middleware issues then I would focus on the execution. One thing I always do when troubleshooting performance is to start with a clean slate. If you are sending over many parameters to a stored procedure and there is no OPTIMIZE hint then you can fall victim to "Parameter Sniffing" and you are relying on a bad cached query plan. To rue this out you can delete the statistics on the tables you are testing and use the WITH RECOMPILE to force the Query Executor to fetch a new optimized Query Plan during each query until you narrow it down.

Comment: @RossBush does that affect sql sent to sp_executesql or sp_prepexec ? Regardless, I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @RossBush - I updated the statistics and notice a marginal improvement. Using the Profiler I'm seeing that the query itself is taking minimal time and the total of the RPC is OK, if not stellar. What I'm really see slow is the overall time. So for a delete by ID, it's 5 ms at most, but the round trip from the cient perspective is more like 700ms.  There is relatively no data transfer, so I can't believe its 350ms in latency??